# Files deleted on a Windows 2003 Network Share from a Windows XP Client

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, file-sharing

I have a Windows 2003 server that has file shares.  If a windows XP client deletes a file on that share.  Does it go to any sort of 'recycle bin' on the server or client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by design.  Files deleted from a network share are just gone without using something like Shadow Copy.  See [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/10032/recycle-bin-for-windows-server-2003-file-shares) for some more ideas on how to provide this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no. 
There are addons that promise to do that. 
Or you could add shadow copies to the server volume so you can roll back.

Answer (score 1):

You are listing 'recovery' as a tag, so I guess this question is for recovery of data that has been deleted by accident. It is not practical in most cases to provide a 'recycle-bin'-functionality.

Instead I suggest you look into [shadow copies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) for the server volume to provide a convenient method to access data that has been modified or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It got deleted on the server, but it got not stored in the recycle bin of the server. You need to take a tool undelete plus or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an article](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2006/07/7383.ars) on Volume Shadow Copy, or "Previous Versions", as it is labelled in the Explorer UI. Should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the recycle bin on a network share if GPOs are used to redirect "My Documents" to the share, anything deleted from "My Documents" will end up in the recycle bin.